# submit form with a virtual property

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I'm currently working with the 2.3 version of the easy-admin bundle in Symfony 4.

I try to create a virtual property for the new view. I have the following configuration:

```
easy-admin:
    entities:
        FieldTemplate:
            class: App\Entity\FieldTemplate                  
            edit: 
                fields:
                    - { property: imageToFill, type_options: { block_prefix: 'field_to_fill'} }
```

according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58710631/6734243 and the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html#virtual-properties), I need to add setter and getter to the virtual entity which I did :

```
//src/Entity/FieldTemplate.php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FieldTemplateRepository")
 */
class FieldTemplate
{
    //virtual functions to display the image of the fieldTemplate in easyadminbundle

    public function getImageToFill()
    {
        return $this->getImage();
    }

    public function setImageToFill()
    {
        //do nothing
        return $this;
    }
```

The field is displayed properly but when I save I get the following error, which suggest that there is no setter for my virtual property.

> Could not determine access type for property "imageToFill" in class "App\Entity\FieldTemplate": Neither the property "imageToFill" nor one of the methods "addImageToFill()"/"removeImageToFill()", "setImageToFill()", "imageToFill()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\FieldTemplate".

Is this behaviour a bug or do I misunderstand something ?

Comment: your config says FieldTemplate::$imageToFill, you added a virtual Field::$imageToFill ... different class ...

Comment: my bad, I made a mistake when writting my question. It's now updated. Still, it's strange because it can actually display the form which mean that the `getter` is found...

Comment: It would be a weird bug. And since you didn't copy your code but apparently wrote it again, maybe you made a typo in your original class? like the classical accent on an i or something... maybe you should check again and/or post the actual original code you have ;o) (really no disrespect, but we can have the most astonishing theories about imaginary code, that all are irrelevant)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I checked and rechecked the functions names (I even copy/paste the required name directly from the error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an easy one. When the form is handled, it send something to the 
`setImageToFill()` property.

> even if the `imageToFill` property is a virtual property and doesn't send anything to the db

So even if it does nothing, add a dummy argument to your `setter` such as

```php
setImageToFill($dummy){
    // do nothing 
    return $this
}
```

and it will work like a charm

Comment: actually thanks for finding that. I didn't expect it to require a parameter but I just checked and it absolutely does.